# Understanding Portugal addresses

Tags: accommodation, language-barrier, portugal

Next week I'll have to visit someone in Porto and hand him an iPhone 11 which is a gift from his father. He is a visitor to Portugal himself. He provided me with a very unusual address.

> Rua Justino Teixeria n 77 1o tras 4300-279

I figured out that 4300-279 is the post code and used Google to find a close address in case he messed up the format and I found something on [booikng.com](https://www.booking.com/hotel/pt/oporto-lovely-house.en-gb.html)

> Rua de Justino Teixeira nº640, Campanhã, 4300-277 Porto, Portugal

So (Rua de Justino Teixeira) is the address but what is with the (n, o and º) symbols?

To make things more complicated he moved from what I assume is a short-let flat to another address

> Praceta quinta da bela vista 133 1o dto 4400-261 Vila Nova de Gaia

I find the (1o) to be the most confusing part unless he made a mistake

Comment: 1o means 1º, sometime the character "o" is used on mistake.

Comment: @CaldeiraG is it in fact a mistake?  I also note that whether or not it is a mistake in Portuguese, the abbreviation *no.* for "number" is standard in English.

Comment: @phoog yeah, some shopping websites don't accept the º, so you can use o for English for example. it's not a big of a mistake, you can tell it's "number" either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not uncommon for Portuguese (and Spanish) adresses, to include the floor on which the apartment is located. [The generally used format for Portugal is](https://youbianku.com/files/upu/PRT.pdf):

```
|---------------------------------  |------------------------------------   |
| MANUEL GASPAR                     | Name + Surname                        |
| LG DR ANTÓNIO VIANA 1, 2o, DTO    | Street + House number, Floor, Side    |
| 1250–096, LISBOA                  | Postcode, Locality                    |
| PORTUGAL                          | Country                               |
|---------------------------------  |------------------------------------   |
```

Floors are specified either with just the number or number and letter - 1, or 1o. Ground floor id  *rés-do-chão* (r/c). Sides can be left, right, and in front - *esquerdo*, *direito*, *frente* - and are often abbreviated - esq, dto, ft. For more details, [this webpage is mighty informative on the topic](https://www.grcdi.nl/gsb/portugal.html#H459588B894012690C5F5F490757C3A54D65FD207032A2AA2APortugalA20A2DA20A5BA5BAddressesA5DA5DA2AA2A00100400F01201501801B02702A02D030).

Answer (score 11):

*1o* means "first" *(primeiro).* The address denotes an apartment on the first floor.

*N<sup>o</sup>* or simply *N* means "number" *(número).*

Comment: And "tras" and "dto" would presumably indicate which door on the given floor. ("Across" and "right" would be my first guess).

Comment: I can confirm the answer and the comment from @HenningMakholm, you are correct (being portuguese myself).

Comment: as a side note, n° is also the short hand for "number" (=numéro) in French.

Comment: @LaurentS. indeed, and in many other languages descended from Latin.  It is also the usual abbreviation in English, though we usually write it without the superscript "o."  A numeral followed by "o" or "a" (depending on gender) is also used in Spanish and Italian, I believe for ordinal numbers.  In English bookbinding usage one sometimes sees *2<sup>o</sup>, 4<sup>o</sup>,* and *8<sup>o</sup>* for [folio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folio), [quarto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto), and [octavo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octavo), respectively.

Comment: @phoog Alas, for some reason HTML <sup> works in answers but not in comments!

Comment: @AndrewLazarus apparently!

Comment: Yeah, not sure why HTML tags and character entities (e.g., &eacute;) work in answers but not comments.

Comment: @DavidRicherby [Why can't we have simple HTML in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12786/156890) on [Meta.SE].